# How to mute the sound of pressing volume keys only in my app on Android?

Tags: android, audio, key, volume, mute

Should I just mute the volume onResume and set the volume level back onPause with AudioManager?

Or is there another proper way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Which volume are you muting, `STREAM_SYSTEM`?

Comment: I just found out it works with STREAM_RING. Not sure it works on every device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer lies in the documentation for [`setStreamMute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute(int,%20boolean)).

> The mute command is protected against
> client process death: if a process
> with an active mute request on a
> stream dies, this stream will be
> unmuted automatically.
>
> The mute
> requests for a given stream are
> cumulative: the AudioManager can
> receive several mute requests from one
> or more clients and the stream will be
> unmuted only when the same number of
> unmute requests are received.
>
> *For a
> better user experience, applications
> MUST unmute a muted stream in
> onPause() and mute is again in
> onResume() if appropriate.*

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, there's a workaround to avoid your app muting everything.
Doing the following, will mute the volume keys and notifications incoming calls will remain as configured in the system (rather than being forcely muted).

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF);
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, true);
```